# how to capture onscroll event of mapview in android?

Tags: android

i wish to make an android applicaiton in which the data to be displayed on the map is dynamically loaded when the user scrolls on the map.
For this i need to capture the onscroll event of the mapview. There is no default onscrolllistener for mapview provided in the sdk.

i have found the following solutions:

1. start a timer task every x seconds to check if the current center of the map is the same as its old center. if not load the new markers.
2. start a ontouchlistener for the map and capture the motion event. The code i am using for this is as following:

   ```
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
           if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
               Log.i("rohan", "onmovement captured");
               GeoPoint gp = ((MapView) arg0).getMapCenter();
               int lat = gp.getLatitudeE6();
               int lng = gp.getLongitudeE6();
               view1CustomAddress =(some url)
               new view1GetMapsInformationThread().execute(null);
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

but the above is not getting called when i scroll through the map.

3.The last and the most tedious of them all is i extend the mapview and then override the compute scroll method.

i do not wish to resort to sol 3. If anybody could tell me a simpler way to capture when the user has scrolled so that i can dynamically load the overlays(this i know how to do) i would be most obliged.

Also if someone could tell me why my sol 2 is not working, it would also be of help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457325/taking-a-picture-with-ontouch-on-x-seconds