# taking a picture with onTouch on X seconds

Tags: java, android

First of all I want to Thank SO for being here for the don`t Know hows.
Second, I am relative new to android programing and doing this for about 2 weeks now.

ok My Question:

I`m Writing an app where you have to ttake a picture when you tap on the screen.
I managed to do that, but in a later stage of the app you can scroll through more then 1 canvas in the live camera view.
So the picture must not be taking when you tap ones on the screen, but when you touch and hold the screen after an X amount of seconds it must take the pucture.

so that if you are scrolling through the canvases you dont take the picture on the moment you hit the screen.

if tried to register the current time on the `ACTION_DOWN` event and compare it with the current time + 5000 (miliseconds) 
are there any sugestions on how to achieve this ?

Kind Regards

`public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            long activateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && activateTime + 5000 == System.currentTimeMillis())
    {
        takePicture();
    }
}
return false;
};
```

EDIT!
this source code was the key for me.

```
public class GestureDemo extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);

}

@Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

}

@Override

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

Toast.makeText(this,"oNDown called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;

}

@Override

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,

float velocityY) {

Toast.makeText(this,"oNFling called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return false;

}

@Override

public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

Toast.makeText(this,"OnLongPress called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,

float distanceY) {

Toast.makeText(this,"onScroll called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;

}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

Toast.makeText(this,"onShowPress called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

Toast.makeText(this,"oNsingleTap called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}

</code>
```

heres the link where I found the [code](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gesture-handling)!

Thank you will for pointing me in the right deriction.

Comment: Your method with the current time and event time doesnt work? It should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way some android components(such as [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html)) do it, is they use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to send delayed messages. So for example, on a ACTION_DOWN event you could call [sendEmptyMessageDelayed(int what, long delayMillis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29), and on ACTION_UP event call [removeMessages(int what)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeMessages%28int%29). If the event is delivered, that means a ACTION_UP never happened, which means the users finger is still down. This ignores the user moving there finger around, though. So you would have set up 'slop' area, and check if they left it with every ACTION_MOVE. Upon the users finger leaving the slop area, you would then cancel the message.

You can read the GestureDetector source code [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java&exact_package=android&q=GestureDetector&type=cs) to see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime() >= 5000)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CAMERA ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```